# Application Crashes on Thread Exit - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, crash, heap-memory

My application is crashing when it exits the thread function.  This is how my thread is initialized:

```
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pThreadStart = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)NotifyWindowThreadFn;
void * pvThreadData = reinterpret_cast<void *>(_pobjSerialPort);

// Create the exit notify window thread event handle.
_hNotifyWindowThreadExitEvent = ::CreateEvent(
    NULL,                           // No security
    TRUE,                           // Create a manual-reset event object
    FALSE,                          // Initial state is non-signaled
    NULL                            // No name specified
    );

if ( _hNotifyWindowThreadExitEvent == NULL )
{
    TRACE(_T("CreateNotifyWindow : Failed to get a handle for the exit message-only window event.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    return ::GetLastError();
}

// Create the notify window thread to begin execution on its own.
_hNotifyWindowThread = ::CreateThread(
    NULL,                           // No security attributes.
    0,                              // Use default initial stack size.
    pThreadStart,                   // Function to execute in new thread.
    pvThreadData,                   // Thread parameters.
    0,                              // Use default creation settings.
    NULL                            // Thread ID is not needed.
    );

if ( _hNotifyWindowThread == NULL )
{
    TRACE(_T("CreateNotifyWindow : Failed to create handle for message-only window thread.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    return ::GetLastError();
}
```

This is the portion of my thread function that gets executed:

```
DWORD NotifyWindowThreadFn( void * pParam )
{
    static CNotifyWindow * pobjNotifyWindow = NULL;
    CSerialPort * pobjSerialPort = reinterpret_cast<CSerialPort *>(pParam);

    // Create notify window to handle surprize removal/insertion events...
    try
    {
        pobjNotifyWindow = new CNotifyWindow();
    }
    catch ( DWORD error )
    {
        return error;                // 1. PC gets here
    }
    catch ( long error )
    {
        return error;
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        return ERROR_CANNOT_MAKE;
    }

    /* Other stuff that is not executed due to return. */

}                                     // 2. PC then gets here
```

When the application crashes, Visual Studio gives me this error message:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in CppTestConsole.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in CppTestConsole.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while CppTestConsole.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

The output window doesn't have anything especially useful.  Only...

> The thread 'NotifyWindowThreadFn' (0x414) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Then it shows that a bunch of DLLs are unloaded.  When I click the Break button, the PC is at the end of `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer` in dbgheap.c.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why my application is crashing when the thread exits?  Should I not be returning directly from within a threaded function?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but it seems like you're trying to create a window from a worker thread.  Don't do this.  Windows need the message pump in order to function, and there's only one message pump in your application -- it's in the main thread.

Comment: Will the `WndProc` function still execute when it receives messages?  I thought that `CreateWindow` does not start the window in a new thread; it executes in the thread that created it.

Comment: I just laughed at myself for saying "trust me."  If someone said that to me, I'd be like, "yeah, right."  Anyway, explain why you think you want your window to run in a worker thread, and we can discuss that.

Comment: Basically, the window is being created only to handle surprise USB removal and insertion events.  It has no user-interface.  When these events are raised, `WndProc` needs to run asynchronously to flag the status of the USB device to the rest of the application ASAP, so that serial I/O with the USB port can be suspended or resumed as needed with minimal impact (i.e. lost data) to the application as possible.

Comment: @Jim:  Is it really WndProc that needs to run asynch?  Or is it the flagging code that is currently in WndProc that needs to run async?  If the latter, them I'd suggest leaving your window in the main thread, and when your trigger fires, kick off a worker thread or signal a sleeping worker thread to do the flagging there.

Comment: Sleeping worker threads take virtually no resources, and it is very common and idiomatic to have worker threads sleeping, waiting for just one signal like this.

Comment: @John Dibling: Thanks, that sounds great in theory, but from what I have read detection of USB events is passed by the Windows OS via messaging.  That is why I have made a window, so its `WndProc` function can evaluate its `uMsg` parameter for `WM_DEVICECHANGE`.  Then, `wParam` can be evaluated for `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` or `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`.

Comment: @Jim:  Then why not simply pass the wParam along to the worker thread, and let it do it's thing?

Comment: @Jim:  Is there a documentation link you can point me to so that I can familiarize myself with what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @John Dibling: This article gives a good overview of the basics: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/device-change-detection.aspx  I'm pretty sure that I need a window to receive system messages, but I'm confused as to whether my `WndProc` function will execute asynchronously on its own.  I could be mistaken, but I had thought that it executes synchronously, which would create a deadlock, hence the thread.  If it will execute asynchronously, then I think I can get rid of the thread altogether.  The last two questions I posted, prior to this one, have code showing how I create the window.

Comment: @Jim Fell : I once (10 years ago) developped a driver and software for a USB device developped by the company I worked for.
And I think what you are trying is at least unusual (don't critisize you ,just warning). 
You don´t communicate directly with a USB-poort ,but which a device on some USB-port. 
Removal of a device should TERMINATE all pending io-operations on that device. You can't suspend because you can't garantee that it's same device it might be an twin-sister/brother of the one you used.
And what about if your device is connected to another USB-port ?

Comment: @John Dibling: Normally, I would agree.  Unfortunately, I am stuck writing driver code for an upgrade of a USB device that is suppose to integrate seamlessly with an existing application (i.e. driver DLL with same externally available APIs).  The way the current application is written, all the port initialization is done on start-up of the application.  Terminating all pending I/O may be feasible; presumably I could simply call my `Close` function when the device is removed and `Open` when it is inserted.

Comment: @John Dibling: I got it working.  The initial problem that led me to post this question turned out to be a bad `malloc`/`free` combo, but the message pump was the key to the larger problem at hand.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you should declare and define you function as : DWORD **WINAPI** NotifyWindowThreadFn( void * pParam )

Comment: +1 to this. In fact, you should not need to cast your function pointer at all. That you need to indicates something is wrong.

Comment: and remove that horrible ,unnecessary and dangerous cast ont it

Comment: @Leo Davidson: well not entirely. If program in C for COM ,you can't do wthou them (i thought).

Comment: @Jim Fell:  If you have use a cast on your windows-procedure then you must remove that as well ,and make that function uses WINAPI.

Comment: I mean if you need to cast a function pointer in that situation. I agree that casts are sometimes needed (e.g. GetProcAddress, or your QueryInterface example).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [_beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.80%29.aspx) instead of CreateThread:

> A thread in an executable that calls
>   the C run-time library (CRT) should
>   use the _beginthreadex and
>   _endthreadex functions for thread management rather than CreateThread
>   and ExitThread; this requires the use
>   of the multi-threaded version of the
>   CRT. If a thread created using
>   CreateThread calls the CRT, the CRT
>   may terminate the process in
>   low-memory conditions.

Comment: @Jim Fell doesn't seem to be doing anythign that would evoke this problem.  Moreover, most (not all) of the problems that arise from using CreateThread() in a thread that uses the CRT have long been fixed.  This is probably not the problem.

Comment: Probably right, although creating a new object shouldn't trash the heap/stack either (even if it is a window). I think Edwin has spotted the problem, though. (Or at least *a* problem. Could be several. :))